# Einstein analytics dashboard filter not showing all values

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics

I have a dashboard in einstein which has a filter based on case type. The case type is a picklist field and has 8 values. However, when I am using the field as a filter, only 3 of them appear in the filter list. I am pretty sure I have added the right field in the dataset. what could be the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There must be no rows in the dataset having the other 5 values.

Means Other 5 values must not be there in any row in your dataset.
All the rows in datasets  contain one of these 3 values.

You can check this.

Thanks